# Puppeteer - Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: web-crawler, puppeteer

Currently I have my Puppeteer running with a Proxy on Heroku. Locally the proxy relay works totally fine. I however get the error `Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`. I've set all `.env` info in the Heroku `config vars` so they are all available.

Any idea how I can fix this error and resolve the issue?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes! What could cause such an error to occur in the hosted environment and not locally? (updated question)